# Reading incoming SMS messages in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create an application for monitoring incoming SMS messages, and logging an entry. For this, I create one activity class to start launching and one broadcast receiver class.

In manifest file, I declare `uses-permission` and `receiver`. Then I debug and run the application on emulator (AVD 5554). After that, I send SMS using DDBS on the same AVD. Unfortunately, activity screen appeared without error but no log message is on LogCat.

Is there anything I miss in the steps? Plus I used startActivity() in the code.

Comment: I presume your receiver is using the intent filter "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED". Let's see some of your code where logging is supposed to take place.

Comment: public class SMSReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static final String tag="Iamhere";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
 Log.i(tag,"Receive");
 if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
 {
  Log.i(tag,"Message is arrived");
 }
    }
}

Comment: I almost forgot one thing. Today, I test sms application. One send sms message and other class capture that message. When I run that application, SmsManager results in RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE. Plus I try messaging on emulator using ph messaging and this alert show "msg can't be sent, it will be sent when the service become available". I dun know what to do. The above sms application is one of tutorial I found from a site and it seems to work well. Say sth about that pls. Thanks in advance.Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new emulator. Sometimes the network connection of the emulator get's into wonky states. This is usually related to the internet, but can sometimes be the cell connection.